# C#: Return a delegate given an object and a method name

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose I'm given an object and a string that holds a method name, how can I return a delegate to that method (of that method?) ?

Example:

```
MyDelegate GetByName(ISomeObject obj, string methodName)
{
    ...
    return new MyDelegate(...);
}

ISomeObject someObject = ...;
MyDelegate myDelegate = GetByName(someObject, "ToString");

//myDelegate would be someObject.ToString
```

Thanks in advance.

One more thing -- I really don't want to use a switch statement even though it would work but be a ton of code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to use [`Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) to get the right method, and [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) to convert the `MethodInfo` into a delegate. Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

delegate string MyDelegate();

public class Dummy
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Hi there";
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static MyDelegate GetByName(object target, string methodName)
    {
        MethodInfo method = target.GetType()
            .GetMethod(methodName, 
                       BindingFlags.Public 
                       | BindingFlags.Instance 
                       | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        // Insert appropriate check for method == null here

        return (MyDelegate) Delegate.CreateDelegate
            (typeof(MyDelegate), target, method);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
        MyDelegate del = GetByName(dummy, "ToString");

        Console.WriteLine(del());
    }
}
```

Mehrdad's comment is a great one though - if the exceptions thrown by this overload of [Delegate.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f294ye.aspx) are okay, you can simplify `GetByName` significantly:

```
    static MyDelegate GetByName(object target, string methodName)
    {
        return (MyDelegate) Delegate.CreateDelegate
            (typeof(MyDelegate), target, methodName);
    }
```

I've never used this myself, because I normally do other bits of checking after finding the `MethodInfo` explicitly - but where it's suitable, this is really handy :)

Comment: `return (MyDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), target, methodName);` wouldn't do?

Comment: It would, unless you're using XNA or Compact Framework. Then, Jon's solution must be used.

Comment: I was hoping this would catch your eye!  Exactly what I needed -- thanks!

Comment: Yep CreateDelegate can take a method and resolve to a static or instance method. I'm not sure what framework this is available on, says how this works to call private methods starting with 2.0 but then it says you should target 3.5....I love msdn

Answer (score 3):

```
static MyDelegate GetByName(object obj, string methodName)
{
    return () => obj.GetType().InvokeMember(methodName, 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null); 
}
```

Comment: If the method is incorrect, that will only fail when you try to invoke the delegate, which is generally not as useful as catching the problem early.

Comment: Yes, It does the job though, and in some circumstances, this might even be desirable.

Comment: Assuming that the method has no parameters, and if you have to call it more then once you don't mind the overhead

Answer (score 1):

Even easier is to use:

```
    public static MyDelegate GetByName(object target, string methodName)
    {
        return (MyDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), 
               target, methodName);
    }
```

Notice that CreateDelegate has an overload which takes the methodName for you. This was done with .net 3.5 Sp1

Comment: The MSDN page suggests it's been in since .NET 1.0... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f294ye.aspx

Comment: Yep I've been reading that page and it must be just a little confused by the wording in the note on the page.

Comment: I think the 3.5 bit is only about using non-public methods.

Comment: I thought that as well, but it states: "Starting with the  NET Framework version 2.0 Service Pack 1". I guess you could read this as I can write code against .net2.0 but when building I need target .net3.5. Either way its not very clear.