# Building delegate handler collection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have an implementation building a delegate handler collection.

```
   public class DelegateHandler
   {
            internal delegate object delegateMethod(object args);
            public IntPtr PublishAsyncMethod(MethodInfo method, MethodInfo callback)
            {
                RuntimeMethodHandle rt;

                try
                {
                    rt = method.MethodHandle;
                    delegateMethod dMethod = (delegateMethod)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                        (typeof(delegateMethod), method.ReflectedType, method, true);
                    AsyncCallback callBack = (AsyncCallback)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                        (typeof(AsyncCallback), method.ReflectedType, callback, true);

                    handlers[rt.Value] = new DelegateStruct(dMethod, callBack);
                    return rt.Value;
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentException ArgEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*****: " + ArgEx.Source);
                    Console.WriteLine("*****: " + ArgEx.InnerException);
                    Console.WriteLine("*****: " + ArgEx.Message);
                }

                return new IntPtr(-1);
            }
   }
```

I publish using the following:

```
 ptr = DelegateHandler.Io.PublishAsyncMethod(
    this.GetType().GetMethod("InitializeComponents"),
    this.GetType().GetMethod("Components_Initialized"));
```

And the method I'm creating a delegate from:

```
    public void InitializeComponents(object args)
    { 
           // do stuff;
    }
```

And the callback method:

```
public void Components_Initialized(IAsyncResult iaRes)
{
       // do stuff;
}
```

Now, I've also already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783108/c-return-a-delegate-given-an-object-and-a-method-name) to get an idea of what I might be doing wrong. The CreateDelegate(...) is causing me to receive:

```
*****: mscorlib
*****: 
*****: Error binding to target method.
```

What is wrong? The methods reside in a different, non-static public class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: These methods will have parameters and return values. As I understand `Action`, and `Action<T>`, this would not be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

First, you are passing incorrect arguments to `CreateDelegate`. Since you are binding to instance methods, you need to pass the instance to which the delegates will be bound, but you are passing `method.ReflectedType` instead of a reference to an object of the class that declares `InitializeComponents` and `Components_Initialized`.

Second, the signature of `InitializeComponents` does not match the declaration of delegate `dMethod`. The delegate has an `object` return type yet `InitializeComponents` returns `void`.

The following should work:

```
// return type changed to void to match target.
internal delegate void delegateMethod(object args);

// obj parameter added
public static void PublishAsyncMethod(object obj, MethodInfo method, MethodInfo callback)
{
    delegateMethod dMethod = (delegateMethod)Delegate.CreateDelegate
        (typeof(delegateMethod), obj, method, true);

    AsyncCallback callBack = (AsyncCallback)Delegate.CreateDelegate
         (typeof(AsyncCallback), obj, callback);

}

DelegateHandler.PublishAsyncMethod(
    this, // pass this pointer needed to bind instance methods to delegates.
    this.GetType().GetMethod("InitializeComponents"),
    this.GetType().GetMethod("Components_Initialized"));
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Awesome!!! The signature for 'delegateMethod' with the return type was an oversight in the post. I had been simplifying the whole thing and simply forgot to show that.

However, this is definitely what I needed. I am sure that I had actually tried passing the target object - nonetheless, we have it right this time. Thanks again...