# Use variable in place of function name

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the following right now:

```
foreach (string file in files) {
    switch (filetype.Value) {
        case "ReadFile":
            ReadFile(file);
            break;
        case "ReadMSOfficeWordFile":
            ReadMSOfficeWordFile(file);
            break;
        case "ReadMSOfficeExcelFile":
            ReadMSOfficeExcelFile(file);
            break;
        case "ReadPDFFile":
            ReadPDFFile(file);
            break;
    }
}
```

It works, but it feels kinda wrong. The Python way would be something more like this:

```
foreach string file in files:
    filetype.Value(file)
```

I have a really hard time imagining that C# can't do something like this. It may be that my Google skills are bad, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**SOLUTION**

```
public static readonly IDictionary<string, Action<string>> FileTypesDict = new Dictionary<string,Action<string>> {
    {"*.txt", ReadFile},
    {"*.doc", ReadMSOfficeWordFile},
    {"*.docx", ReadMSOfficeWordFile},
    {"*.xls", ReadMSOfficeExcelFile},
    {"*.xlsx", ReadMSOfficeExcelFile},
    {"*.pdf", ReadPDFFile},
};
```

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>> filetype in FileTypesDict) {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, filetype.Key, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    //System.Reflection.MethodInfo ReadFileMethod = ReadFile.GetType().GetMethod(filetype.Value);
    foreach (string file in files) {
        FileTypesDict[filetype.Key](file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to figure out what is filetype ?

Comment: Consider making the switch values enum instead of string. Not a solution to your problem but a good practice to make sure you catch errors compile time.

Comment: Show us the way you obtain/construct ``fileType``s. Possibly a minor change there (supplying a delegate instead of string) makes it all go away easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with some preparation using delegates, like this:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string,Action<string>> actionByType =
    new Dictionary<string,Action<string>> {
        {"ReadFile", ReadFile}
    ,   {"ReadMSOfficeWordFile", ReadMSOfficeWordFile}
    ,   {"ReadMSOfficeExcelFile", ReadMSOfficeExcelFile}
    ,   {"ReadPDFFile", ReadPDFFile}
    };
```

When it is time to call your action, do it as follows:

```
actionByType[actionName](file);
```

Comment: Python can do that because it's a dynamic language. Even though c# has support for dynamic types it's not a dynamic language. That's why you need to use something like this

Comment: I like this but I'm seeing the error:

    Error 3 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>'

Comment: @MTeck Are your `XYZFile(...)` methods all have the same signature? Do they take `RegularExpressions.Group`? Also are your `XYZFile(...)` methods all static?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  static void ReadMSOfficeWordFile(string file) { }  They're all just like that. file is a string containing the file name.

Comment: @MTeck Then you need to replace `FileInfo` with string (see my last edit).

Comment: PERFECT! That's actually not much less dynamic than the Python way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a delegate:

```
Action<string> action;
switch (filetype.Value) {
  case "ReadFile":
    action = ReadFile;
    break;
  case "ReadMSOfficeWordFile":
    action = ReadMSOfficeWordFile;
    break;
  case "ReadMSOfficeExcelFile":
    action = ReadMSOfficeExcelFile;
    break;
  case "ReadPDFFile":
    action = ReadPDFFile;
    break;
  default: 
    throw new NotImplementedException("Unhandled file type '"+filetype.Value+"'.");
}
foreach (string file in files) {
  action(file);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could keep a `Dictionary` of delegates, as the simplest way:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<string>> fileReaders = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>() {
    {"ReadFile", ReadFile},
    {"ReadOfficeWordFile", ReadOfficeWordFile},
    {"ReadOfficeExcelFile", ReadOfficeExcelFile},
    {"ReadPDFFile", ReadPDFFile}
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
fileReaders[fileType.Value](file);
```

Depending on what your methods return, you may have to change the type of the delegate (`Action<string>` means `void something(string someparam)` as a method signature, for example) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for will need some refactoring of your code.

All of your "cases" (TextFile, MSOfficeWordFile, MSOfficeExcelFile, PdfFile) should be their own classes which implement a single interface.

Your interface should be named something like "IReadableFile" and specify a method named "ReadFile()".

Each class should have their own implementation of "ReadFile()"

Example:

```
public interface IReadableFile
{
    void ReadFile();
}
```

---

```
public class MSOfficeWordFile : IReadableFile
{
    public void ReadFile()
    {
        ReadMSOfficeWordFile(file);
    }
}
```

---

```
foreach(IReadableFile file in files)
    file.ReadFile();
```

Code may contain some mistakes, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use reflection (if you're okay with the different overhead that can bring)
Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783108/c-return-a-delegate-given-an-object-and-a-method-name)

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to avoid the explicit mapping of method names to string values you could use reflection to do dynamic method invocation (this assumes filetype.Value is of type `String`)

```
String method_name = String.Empty;
foreach (string file in files) {
    method_name = filetype.Value;
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(method_name);
    method.Invoke(this, new object[]{file});
}
```