# Variable as function call from external XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a text file parser for a specific matching condition, and in a couple of the files I need to do some custom manipulation. What I would like to do is store the name of the custom procedure that is being used in an external XML file with the other rules. Most won't use this, and I found this answer regarding the action call:

[Variable for function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586183/use-variable-in-place-of-function-name)

The above has the following dictionary definition

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string,Action<string>> actionByType =
    new Dictionary<string,Action<string>>
```

Element adding from XML file in my current program (These two elements will be added)

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Client holding = new Client();

                holding.has_custom = 
                     Convert.ToBoolean(
                      node.SelectSingleNode("has_custom").InnerText);
                holding.custom_call = 
                     node.SelectSingleNode("custom_call").InnerText;

                clients.Add(holding);
            }
```

As I go through this, how do I assign the name of the custom call as an action to be called in the dictionary? And then do I use a case statement with the generic parse as the default?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In your example, `actionByType` _is_ a dictionary. What are you proposing as an alternative?

Comment: @JLRishe - Edited and clarified I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can assign Actions / functions (Delegates to be more specific) like this:

```
actionByType.Add("write", text => Console.WriteLine(text));
actionByType.Add("write2", Console.WriteLine);
```

or like this:

```
void someAction(string someString)
{
     Console.WriteLine(someString);
}

...
actionByType.Add("write", someAction);
```

Then Invoke like this:

```
actionByType["write"]("Hello World!");
```

So in your case it would be:

```
actionByType[holding.custom_call]("What ever you need that string argument for");
```

Here is the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/oFuEeF

Answer (score 0):

First, get the proper [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection.methodinfo) using reflection. This should be a static method, and should reside in a static class containing all your XML-accessible methods.

```
var method = typeof(MyStoredTypes).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
```

You'll also need a [ParameterExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to capture the incoming string.

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
```

Finally, [System.Linq.Expression.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349020%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the Expression tree for your call, [Lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340145%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it, and [Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it.

```
var act = Expression.Lambda<Action<string>>(
    Expression.Call(param, method),
    new ParameterExpression[] { param })
.Compile();
```