# When trying to create a delegate with methodinfo.createdelegate I get and error: 'ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I'm trying to create a delegate with Delegate.CreateDelegate I am getting the error:

ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure, System.Boolean allowClosed) (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure) (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)

This is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < statusMoves.Length; i++)
    {
        StatusMovesMethods moveMethods = new StatusMovesMethods();

        MethodInfo theMethod = moveMethods.GetType().GetMethod(statusMoves[i].name);

        moveMethod = (Move.MoveMethod)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Move.MoveMethod), theMethod);
        statusMoves[i].moveMethod = moveMethod;
    }
```

And this is where moveMethod is initialized

```
public delegate void MoveMethod(Battler target);
public MoveMethod moveMethod;
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Move.MoveMethod` and the methods named by the names in `statusMoves`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still don't know why it was giving me an error but I found a way to fix it, I found [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783108/c-return-a-delegate-given-an-object-and-a-method-name) where someone had a similar question and I used the code from there like this:

```
void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < statusMoves.Length; i++)
    {
        statusMoves[i].moveMethod = GetByName(moveMethods, statusMoves[i].name);
    }
}

static Action GetByName(object target, string methodName)
{
    MethodInfo method = target.GetType()
        .GetMethod(methodName,
                   BindingFlags.Public
                   | BindingFlags.Instance
                   | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    // Insert appropriate check for method == null here

    return (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate
        (typeof(Action), target, method);
}
```

Hope this helps someone